# Converting a char array with decimal numbers to different float

Tags: c

Hello I´m fairly new to C programming and i want to convert a char array looking like

```
char numberlist[]="9,8 2,3 5,4 2,7 1,3";
```

to a float that would be 9.8 ,i used

```
float a;
 a=atof(numberlist);
printf("%.1f\n",a);
```

but that gave me 9.0 in return because it is 9,8 instead of 9.8 in the char array. How could i easily fix that, without touching the char array?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Explain more about the role of "2,3 5,4 2,7 1,3".

Comment: You may need to play with [`localeconv`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/locale/localeconv) and [`struct lconv`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/locale/lconv) or just extract the two parts as integers and compose those in a floating point value (e.g. 9 + 8/10.0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example

```
char numberlist[]="9,8 2,3 5,4 2,7 1,3";

float convertFirstNumber(const char *str, char delim)
{
    char z[256];
    size_t index = 0;

    while(*str && *str != delim)
    {
        if(*str == ',') z[index++] = '.';
        else z[index++] = *str;
        str++;
    }
    z[index] = 0;
    return atof(z);
}

int main()
{
    printf("%.1f\n",convertFirstNuber(numberlist, ' '));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with `int sscanf(const char *restrict s, const char *restrict format, ...);` and `atof` i have chossed `sscanf` to show u different approach. you can replace it with `atof` if you wish.

```
int main(){

    float f, resd;
    int i = 0;
    char numberlist[]="9,8 2,3 5,4 2,7 1,3";

    sscanf(numberlist,"%f",&f);

    while(numberlist[i] != ','){
        ++i;
    }

    sscanf(&numberlist[i],",%f",&resd);
    printf("%f\n", resd);
    printf("%f",f+resd/10.0);

return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your string uses a comma as decimal point, you could set the locale to a useful value before parsing:

```
   /* Set number locale to german */
   setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "de_DE.utf8");

   double a; /* Never use floats */ 
   sscanf("3,14", "%lf", &a);

   /* It is better to not hardcode "C" but use the locale saved before the 
      previous `setlocale` */
   setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "C");
   /* Should print "3.14" */
   printf("%lf\n", a);
```

Just remember that `setlocale` has issues with multithreaded software. And you should reconsider if you *really* want to store your data with comma as the decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

Adam gave a good answer.

You can also iterate the string and create the number manually.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <math.h>

char numberlist[] = "9,8 2,3 5,4 2,7 1,3";

int main() {
    int len = strlen(numberlist);
    int total = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = len; i >= 0; i--){
        char c = numberlist[i];
        if(isdigit(c)){
            int number = atoi(&c);
            total += round(pow(10, count)) * number;
            count++;
        }
    }
    float value = total / round(pow(10, count-1));
    printf("%.2f\n", value);

}
```